# Import Script is stopped even we set all apache/php/server/mysql config with high values

Tags: php, import, timeout

PHP Import Script is stopped even we set all apache/php/server/mysql config with high values

- before we had timeout from mysql we set timeout at 500
- than timeout from php we set timeout to 20000

> ```
> max_execution_time = 20000
> mail.add_x_header = On
> upload_max_filesize = 3G
> post_max_size = 8G
> memory_limit = 8G
> ```

- than "Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

we set apache timeout at 15000 .Server is a 8 core 64GB ram server LINUX  /PLESK Apache log, php logs, my sql logs have No useful info :/

What other we could do?  Any Idea? 
thank you

Comment: What is this import script exactly doing? Think about bypassing at least Apache and execute php directly with the php interpreter.

Comment: Can you post a copy of the script ?

Comment: is the error reporting on ? if not then try this : `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>`

Comment: the script donwload a csv, import the data in a temp table, than check every records and import only the one that is not already in the DB. The file is quite big... but It is stopped after 5 min and 1000 rows processed

Comment: no no error reported in logs. I try with your suggestion, thank you